# Unique solution of the equation $ f (x) f (y)=f (p) f (q) $ given $x+y=p+q$ and $ x^2+y^2=p^2+q^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Unique solution of  the equation $ f (x) f (y)=f (p) f (q) $ given $x+y=p+q$ and $ |x|^2+|y|^2=|p|^2+|q|^2 $ $\quad$ $f(x) \ge 0$ and $\int f dx^N > 0$

$ x, y,p, q $ are vectors (Euclidean  space) that is each vector has 3 components. The function $ f $ is measurable. $ x.y $ is dot product as defined in Euclidean geometry.

Please could you  state and explain if unique solution exist?

Ofcourse $f (x)=Ae^{b|x|^2+c.x+d}$ solves it but must it be of this form?

Comment: What is $f$? Also, are any of $x,y,p,q$ given? I'm not sure what the question is asking for.

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $f$? For example, does it need to be continuous? Differentiable? Is it a function on the reals? Does the equation hold for *all* $x,y,p,q$ satisfying those two conditions?

Comment: Vectors in what space? Also how do you define $x^2$?

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. I made corrections.

Comment: Where, exactly, did you get the question???????

Comment: @Will jagy. answer available now.

Answer (score 0):

If $x+y=p+q$ and $x^2+y^2=p^2+q^2$ then 
$$2xy=(x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2)=(p+q)^2-(p^2+q^2)=2pq$$

Therefore 
$$(x-y)^2=(p-q)^2 \Rightarrow |x-y|=|p-q| \Rightarrow x-y=\pm (p-q)$$

If $x-y=p-q$ then since $x+y=p+q$ you get $x=p, y=q$ and hence $f(x)f(y)=f(p)f(q)$.

If $x-y=-(p-q)$ then since $x+y=p+q$ you get $x=q, y=p$ and hence $f(x)f(y)=f(p)f(q)$.

Comment: So, in short, every function $f$ satisfies this?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes :).

Comment: Sorry my bad. The question was  not clear. I made corrections.

Comment: @Wojuwu. answer available now.

Answer (score 0):

The most general form of Maxwell's theorem:

$ f:R^N \to [0 , \infty] $ ,  $ f $ is measurable

$ x, y,p, q \in R^N $

Solve $ f (x) + f (y) = f (p) + f ( q) $, under the conditions :$ x+y=p+q, x^2+y^2=p^2+q^2$. Where $ x^2$ is the norm of $ x $

$\psi (x, y)=f (x) f (y) $

$ \psi (x, y) $ is constant whenever $ x+y, x^2+y^2$ is constant. Therefore $\psi (x, y)= G (x+y, x^2+y^2) $

$f (x, x^2) f (y, y^2)= G (x+y, x^2+y^2) $

$f (u, v^2) f (w,z^2)= G (u+w, v^2+z^2) $

If there is $ u,v$ such that $ f (u, v^2) =0$ implies $ G (u+w, v^2+z^2)=0$ . Since $ w,z $ are arbitrary, it implies $ G(a,b^2)=0$ for all $ a, b \in R^N $ which implies $ f (n, m^2) =0$ for all $ n,m \in R^N $

Since $\int f dx^N > 0$, base on the result above $ f> 0$

$\varphi (x, x^2)=log (f (x, x^2)) $

$\varphi(x, x^2)+\varphi(y, y^2)=F (x+y, x^2+y^2)$

So $\varphi (x, x^2)+\varphi(y, y^2)=F(x+y,x^2+y^2)$

$$\varphi_1(x, x^2)=\varphi(x, x^2)-\varphi(0,0)$$

$$\varphi_1(y, y^2)=\varphi(y, y^2)-\varphi(0,0)$$

$$F_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)=F(x+y,x^2+y^2)-F(0,0)$$

so that $\varphi_1(0,0)=F_1(0,0)=0$

$$\varphi_1(x, x^2) +\varphi_1(y, y^2)=F_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)$$

plug $y=0$ into the equation above and get $\varphi_1(x, x^2)=F_1(x,x^2)$ and similarly $\varphi_1(y, y^2)=F_1(y,y^2)$

Therefore $\varphi_1(x,x^2) +\varphi_1(y,y^2)=\varphi_1(x+y,x^2+y^2)$

$$\varphi_1(u,v^2) =\varphi_1(u,0)+\varphi_1(0,v^2)$$

let $f(u)=\varphi_1(u,0)$ , and $g(v)=\varphi_1(0,v^2)$

$$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$$

$$g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$$

By solution of Cauchy functional equation for measurable functions: $f(u)=b\cdot u$ $\quad$ $g(v)=av^2$  $\quad$ and $\varphi_1(x,x^2)=ax^2+b\cdot x$ $a\cdot e \quad$ $\varphi(x,x^2)=\varphi_1(x,x^2)+\varphi(0,0)$ $a\cdot e$ set $\varphi(0,0)=c$

$\varphi(x,x^2)=ax^2+b\cdot x+c$ $\quad$

$f(x) = e^{ax^2+bx+c}=Ae^{ax^2+bx}$ $\quad a\cdot e$ where $A=e^c$

Comment: What if $f$ can be negative? Or do you implicitly assume this cannot be?

Comment: yes $f(x) \ge 0$. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: @Wojowu it can't be negative

Answer (score 0):

Here's a line of argument to show that if $a+b=c+d$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, then $a=c$, $b=d$.

If possible, let there be non-zero integers $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$a+b=c+d\\ a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$$
Square the first equation and substract the second from it to get
$$ab=cd$$
which means that the determinant of
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&d\\ c&b\end{pmatrix}$$
is $0$, which means $[a\;\;\; d]=k\cdot [c\;\;\; b]$ for some $k$. But, since $a+b=c+d$, we must have $k=1$ which gives $a=c$ and $b=d$.